# Nested Json parsing with GSon

Tags: android, json, list, parsing, gson

How to parse below Json Response with google Gson.?

```
{
   "rootobject":[
      {
         "id":"7",
         "name":"PP-1",
         "subtitle":"name-I",
         "key1":"punjab",
         "key12":"2013",
         "location":"",
         "key13":"0",
         "key14":"0",
         "key15":"0",
         "result_status":null
      },
      {
         "id":"7",
         "name":"PP-1",
         "subtitle":"name-I",
         "key1":"punjab",
         "key12":"2013",
         "location":"",
         "key13":"0",
         "key14":"0",
         "key15":"0",
         "result_status":null
      },
      {
         "id":"7",
         "name":"PP-1",
         "subtitle":"name-I",
         "key1":"punjab",
         "key12":"2013",
         "location":"",
         "key13":"0",
         "key14":"0",
         "key15":"0",
         "result_status":null
      },
      {
         "id":"7",
         "name":"PP-1",
         "subtitle":"name-I",
         "key1":"punjab",
         "key12":"2013",
         "location":"",
         "key13":"0",
         "key14":"0",
         "key15":"0",
         "result_status":null
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd create objects to "wrap" the response, such as:

```
public class Response {

  @SerializedName("root_object")
  private List<YourObject> rootObject;

  //getter and setter
}


public class YourObject {

  @SerializedName("id")
  private String id;
  @SerializedName("name")
  private String name;
  @SerializedName("subtitle")
  private String subtitle;
  //... other fields

  //getters and setters
}
```

Note: use @SerializedName annotation to follow naming conventions in your Java attribute while matching the names in the JSON data.

Then you just parse the JSON with your `Reponse` object, like this:

```
String jsonString = "your json data...";
Gson gson = new Gson();
Response response = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Response.class);
```

Now you can access all the data in your `Response` object using getters and setters.

Note: your `Response` object may be used to parse different JSON responses. For example you could have JSON response that don't contain the `id` or the `subtitle` fields, but your `Reponse`object will parse the response as well, and just put a `null` in this fields. This way you can use only one `Response`class to parse all the possible responses...

EDIT: I didn't realise the Android tag, I use this approach in a usual Java program, I'm not sure whether it's valid for Android...

Comment: But i am getting list of objects..?How can i annotate it..?

RootObject further contains list of objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this hope this will work

```
 // Getting Array 
JSONArray contacts = json.getJSONArray("rootobject");
SampleClass[] sample=new SampleClass[contacts.length]();

    // looping through All 
    for(int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++){
        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

        // Storing each json item in variable
        sample[i].id = c.getString("id");
        sample[i].name = c.getString("name");
        sample[i].email = c.getString("subtitle");
        sample[i].address = c.getString("key1");
        sample[i].gender = c.getString("key12");
        sample[i].gender = c.getString("location");
        sample[i].gender = c.getString("key13");
        sample[i].gender = c.getString("key14");
        sample[i].gender = c.getString("key15");
        sample[i].gender = c.getString("result_status");
       }
```