# Retrieving a JSON object from a server with JSP

Tags: json, jsp

I am new to JSP and I am having trouble finding a simple concrete example to make a request to a server that returns a JSON object.
What I am trying to do is something like:

`myjson_object = getJSONfrom("my.webserver.com/get/json")`

I basically want to add such a line to an existing JSP page so that I can have the JSON object available. I would like to avoid using AJAX or JQuery. I have found several examples like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185559/jsp-make-http-get-request-and-get-json-response), but for some reason they do not work in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably trying to do that operation into JSP is not a good idea, since you'd need to use scriptlets and I understand scriptlets are now considered not a good practice (see [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files))... You'd better do it into a servlet (see [**this**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/servlets-jsp-140445.html))...

Anyway the code would be similar. You first need to make the request and then parse the JSON response...

1. In order to make the request you can use [`HttpURLConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) class. See [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests).
2. Once you have the server response into a [`BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html), you can parse the JSON using some library, such as [**Gson**](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). You can find lots of examples of JSON deserializing using Gson in SO, like [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16377754/parse-json-file-using-gson/16378782#16378782) or [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15851190/nested-json-parsing-with-gson/15851373#15851373).

Comment: Thank you very much for your complete answer. I also found this other answer which uses JSTL to read and parse the JSON object. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829643/processing-json-objects-in-jsp